# Java subclass as parameter

Tags: java, subclass, extends

```
Class A
Class B extends A
```

---

```
public static List<A> doSomething(List<A> items, A item) {
    // manipulate items
    return items;
}
```

---

```
List<B> items = new ArrayList<B>();
B item = new B();

items = doSomething(items, item);
```

> ERROR: The method doSomething(List< A>, A) is not applicable for the arguments (List< B>, B)

item is accepted, but items in not.
Why Can't I do that?

And how is the correct way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`List<B>` does not extend `List<A>`.  There are good reasons for that; informally, consider that the contract for `List<A>` "*you can put an instance of A in it*" is not valid for `List<B>`.

You need to indicate that you are willing to accept lists with subtypes of `A`.  You can do that with a wildcard like `List<? extends A>`.  However then your return type also becomes `List<? extends A>` and you don't want that.  What you really want is that if you pass in `List<B>`, the return type is `List<B>`.

To do this properly without casts, you need to bind the type and specify it can sublass A.

```
public static <T extends A> List<T> doSomething(List<T> items, T item) {
    // manipulate items
    return items;
}
```

This should work.

Comment: Thank you, I prefer this solution.

Answer (score 8):

You have to use `List<? extends A>`.

Comment: To expand on this, the reason you can't use a `List<B>` in place of `List<A>` is because Java's generics are invariant -- that is, `Something<Superclass>` is *not* a superclass of `Something<Subclass>`, unlike arrays, where `Superclass[]` is a superclass of `Subclass[]`

Comment: Thankyou, I did the ? extends A thing but had problems with the return, I had to cast it.

Answer (score 1):

Even if B is subclass of A, List is not a subclass of List.

You should change your method in this way:

```
public  static  List<? extends A>doSomething(List<? extends A> items, A item) {
    // manipulate items
    return items;
}
```

and call it by casting the return value:

```
items = (List<B>) doSomething(items, item);
```

Be aware that in this way you can call the method passing as a parameter also a List of other potentially subclasses of A, and then the return value will be a List of that subclass (i.e. not a List), so it is your responsibility to know if the cast is legal or not.

Comment: Thankyou, what I was missing was the cast of the return.

Comment: @SimoneConti you don't need the cast; see my answer

Comment: @JoeriHendrickx you're right, your solution is more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

I think both items and item are not accepted. if you replace  like wise

```
List<A> items = new ArrayList<A>();
B item = new B();

items = doSomething(items, item);
```

Now you will get the

> ERROR: The method doSomething(List< A>, A) is not applicable for the
>   arguments (List< A>, B)